# Ошибка: "unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE"

Tags: php

Проблема в регистрации.

Помогите, у меня проблема: пишет синтаксическая ошибка. Вот, что пишет:

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in Z:\home\php\www\index.php on line 29.`

А вот где якобы ошибка

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])).
```

**Дополнено из комментария**.

```
<?php
if    (!isset($myrow['avatar']) or $myrow['avatar']=='') {

print    <<<HERE
<form    action="testreg.php" method="post">
<p>
<label>Ваш логин:<br></label>
<input    name="login" type="text" size="15"    maxlength="15"
HERE;

if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) 
{
echo    ' value="'.$_COOKIE['login'].'">';
}          
print <<<HERE 
</p>
<p>
```

Кто знает, помогите, очень нужно.

Comment: Синтаксическая ошибка, выложи кусок кода, а  if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) написано правильно !

Comment: Покажите запрос к БД, думаю, что ошибка там.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот контент взят с сайта? Вот так и знал, что тут `heredoc`))

Вся проблема в

```
print <<<HERE
бла бла бла
HERE;
```

Запомните две вещи по этому поводу:

1. После

   ```
   print <<<HERE
   ```

   на той же строке НИЧЕГО быть не должно, никаких знаков, цифр, букв, **пробелов** только переход на новую строку.
2. Закрывающий тэг `HERE;` ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО должен начинаться с самого начала строки. Так же после него ничего быть не должно! Только переход на новую строку.

В общем, все пробелы, знаки, теги перед и после `print <<<HERE` должны быть удалены, а также все пробелы, знаки, теги перед и после `HERE;` должны быть удалены.
И советую почитать [тут](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Извините. Последний вопрос 
>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in Z:\home\php\www\index.php on line 23
 
Вот что высвечивается.

Comment: @антон нужен код. Проверьте,чтоб рядом с print <<<HERE и HERE; пробелов нигде не было. 100 раз проверьте возможно где-то упустили.

Comment: @антон Поставьте галку за лучший!)